# create a non unique index on symfony2 entity

Tags: php, symfony, indexing, doctrine-orm

What is the correct annotation to create a non unique index ?

Currently i have this:

```
namespace XXX\XXXBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* User
*
* @Table(name="user",indexes={@index(name="role_id", columns={"role_id"})})
* @ORM\Entity
*/

class User {

}
```

The problem is it create a unique index : doctrine is doing the `CREATE INDEX` command but it also does the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` command.

So i have 2 indexes on the same field but since one is unique i cannot have two users with the same role.How to prevent doctrine from executing the 2nd command ?

Thanks.

Comment: No it's not, I tried in one entity and doctrine only dump  CREATE INDEX role_id ON user (role_id);

Answer (score 0):

ok the problem is solved, it was because of a "oneToOne" relationship that created a unique index.

How can i mark this thread as resolved ???